# Best practice for multinomial confidence bounds, given only data from a few categories

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

I have a multinomial distribution with $k$ categories, and my goal is to establish statements of the form: "I am $1-\alpha$ confident that the true frequency of category $i$ is below $x$".

There is a good chance that I will only be told the frequencies of the categories that happened to show up the least. Let's fix $\alpha<.5$ and let $z>0$ be the upper $\alpha$ percentile of the normal distribution.

For a single category $i$, if $O_i$ are the number of times we observe $i$ and $n$ is the total number of observations, I can find the maximum $p_i$ that satisfies:

$\frac{O_i-np_i}{\sqrt{p_i(1-p_i)}}\ge z$

and say that I am $1-\alpha$ confident that the true frequency is less than $p_i$. If I wanted simultaneous bounds for all the categories I am given, I could use Bonferri's correction and divide $\alpha$ by $k$ (even if I am given observations for fewer than $k$ categories). Can I do better?